# Can the accessToken expire time be automatically refreshed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am wondering if anybody know if it is at all possible that the accessToken expiry time be auto 'refreshed'?

Last night when working on my app, after a couple hours away from the computer and came back to see that my app was firing errors due to the token reaching its expiry time.  So I started working on some code to refresh the token in the event of an error.  Today I am trying to test/debug that code, but now the token seems to never expire.

I have a bit of Javascript that is printing the response.authResponse.expiresIn on the screen every 5 seconds... and I watch... as the number ticks down, suddenly it jumps back up to 7000 + (guessing roughly 2 hours) on it's own, without any interaction from myself.

Can Facebook be auto refreshing the token some how?  I cannot test the code that is fired in the event of an error, if there is no error actually being fired.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

The facebook javascript sdk will automatically refresh the token, but other than that you must either [request an extended expiration time](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) or request a new one.

Comment: Thanks - so the Javascript must be refreshing the token - but I am guessing that sometimes it is not, thus the OAuthException errors I was getting last night.  I think my code will catch such errors and refresh the accessToken, but hard to test when I not getting the error on a consistent basis :-)

Comment: @ChrisHawkins: Not Javascript but the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), you are using it right?

Comment: @ifaour: Yes I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK (sorry that is what I meant ;-)).  Perhaps I am using it wrong?

Comment: Well finally got a OAuthException error... so ran the code I wrote to refresh the token and it worked.  Not sure why I was not getting the errors before.  I did notice that the response.authResponse.expiresIn that I was printing on the screen every 5 seconds got down to around low 3000s before resetting to around 7000.  It was at this time I refreshed the browser window and got the error.